# Can I use python watchdog to trigger another file execution

Tags: python, watchdog

I am looking for a way to trigger an event (like executing another py) on monitoring file modification in a directory. Watchdog seems good in file monitoring, but all I found about its triggering is the logging event. Is it possible to trigger another py file execution?

Comment: Are you talking about the fact that the quick start example for `watchdog` (https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/quickstart.html#a-simple-example) just logs the changed file? Because that code ought to be a good starting point for doing anything to the file, not just logging the change. Are you saying you're unable to extrapolate from that example?

Comment: Hi Random! Exactly that I cannot extrapolate from the quick start of watchdog. Do you have any useful example?

Comment: That example already seems pretty good to me, when combined with reading through the API, focusing on the parts they used in the example: https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html I don't have any other suggestions though. If you're still stuck after that it seems like you might need to get more general practice with Python before trying this.